# How to Match Two Strings?

Tags: php

If I want to match two strings like

```
$string1 = 'hello';
$string2 = 'hell';
```

OR

```
$string1 = 'hello';
$string2 = 'hellz';
```

so Result should be like this "4 Character are match".

Comment: You probably need `substr_compare`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php

Comment: http://php.net/levenshtein ?

Comment: you can use `===` operator too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php 
  $s1='hello';
        $s2='hellz';
        $s1_array=str_split($s1);
        $s2_array=str_split($s2);
        $intersect_result=array_intersect($s1_array,$s2_array);
        $matchCount=count($intersect_result);
       echo $matchingCount.' Characters are matched';
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string1 = 'hello';
$string2 = 'hell';

$matchingCount = 0;
for($n = 0; $n < max(strlen($string1), strlen($string2)); $n++) {
    if(substr($string1, $n, 1) == substr($string2, $n, 1)) {
        $matchingCount++;
    }
}

echo $matchingCount.' Character are match';
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>